# How to test a function that you don't have direct access to

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs, react-testing-library

I'm trying to test a `dispatch` function destructured from `useReducer`.

My dispatch function is created within my component so, as far as I can tell, I'm not able to `expect(dispatch).toHaveBeenCalledWith({...})` like I normally would.

My Component looks something like this:

```
const reducer = (state, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case 'MY_ACTION':
            return { ...state, myError: action.payload };
    }
};

const Container = ({ someProp, anotherProp, aThirdProp }) => {

    // This hook only works at this level of my application

    const onlyAvailableInsideContainer = useonlyAvailableInsideContainer();



    // Due to the above my initial state needs to be created here

    const initialState = {
        initialStateArr: [],
        someProp,
        myError: null,
        aThirdProp,
        anotherProp,
        onlyAvailableInsideContainer,
    };



    // Which means I need to extract my state and dispatch functions within the Container also

    const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(reducer, initialState);

    const { fieldProps, formProps, errors } = someHook(
        hookConfig(state, dispatch, aThirdProp, onlyAvailableInsideContainer),
    );

    return (
        <div className="dcx-hybrid">
            <MyContext.Provider
                value={{ state, dispatch, fieldProps, formProps, errors }}
            >
                <SomeChildComponent />
            </MyContext.Provider>
        </div>
    );
};
```

I need to test the dispatch function destructured from `useReducer`, but am unable to access it (as far as I can tell).

Ideally my initial state and useReducers would be created exclusively from my component, but I need information that is only accessible from within.

Something like this is what I think I need to do, but I don't know how to format the test in a way that it knows what I'm trying to do.

```
function renderContainer(props) {
    // eslint-disable-next-line react/jsx-props-no-spreading
    const utils = render(<Container {...props} />);

    return {
        ...utils,
    };
}

test('an error will be disatched when the endpoint returns a 4xx status', async () => {
    fetchMock.post('/api/myendpoint', 400);

    const component = renderContainer();

    await act(async () => {
        fireEvent.click(component.getByText('Continue'));
    });

    expect(dispatch).toBeCalledWith({
        type: 'MY_ACTION',
        payload: 'Some error message.',
    });
});
```

Comment: Test the result of the call, not the call itself.

Comment: @HereticMonkey I've done this - My issue is I've still got missed lines in my coverage table :(

Comment: How did you do that? Which lines are missed?

Comment: @jonrsharpe In a very similar way to the above.  I check for the existence of an element that renders post click/dispatch.  But I still get uncovered lines in my reducer for the actual case

Comment: Just make sure your test is exercising all the possible inputs to the function, or in your case, all of the inputs to the parent function that generate the possible inputs to the child function.

Comment: @HereticMonkey I'll give that a go!!  Thank you :)

Comment: try mocking or spying on  `useReducer `?

Comment: @adel how would I do that?

Comment: i have posted an answer you can try it.

Answer (score 1):

try spying on `useReducer` like this:

```
const dispatch= jest.fn();
const useReducerMock= (reducer,initialState) => [initialState, dispatch];
jest.spyOn(React, 'useReducer').mockImplementation(useReducerMock);
```

then test it :

```
   expect(dispatch).toBeCalledWith({
        type: 'MY_ACTION',
        payload: 'Some error message.',
    });
```

Comment: I would strongly recommend *not* spying on parts of React - don't mock what you don't own.

Comment: @jonrsharpe you are right but he want to test the function call, it's better to test the ui for this action.